# Change background image in blender

Tags: grease-pencil

could anyone advise how to change background image in different key frames in 2d animation? I need to have one background image on the 1st frame and other images on other frames. If i change a background image on the 2nd frame then it is automatically changed on the 1st frame. It looks like i can have only one background image on all key frames or not?

Comment: Hi and welcome Anna! Just curious: Does one of our answers solve your issue? If no, do you mind adding more details to your question? I recommend take the tour to see how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Select your *Background Image* (*Empty*), go to *Properties > Object Data > Image*, set the *Source* property to *Image Sequence* or *Movie* and select your clip using the *File Browser*:

[image]

Manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/empties.html

Comment: Empties are not rendered, can they be?

Comment: As I understand the question it's not about rendering rather using the background to actually do some rotoscoping with grease pencil -> .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping @lemon

Answer (score 1):

In case this is for world background image, you can also do it.

[image]

Add an environment texture node.

Open the image files from it: if you select several files, Blender will now this is a sequence.

Now you can keyframe the *"offset"* value of the node.

Finally, you'll just need to set the animation extrapolation to constant (if the images are not frame numbered sequentially).

[image]

You'll need to name the files like that so Blender can attach a frame to each:

[image]